# Iterate through items from SOAP-xml result in php

Tags: php, xml, soap

i'm trying with no success to iterate throug an xml string. I did it before and it worked fine.
I get this from a SOAP server doing this:

```
$lr = $client->__doRequest($request, $url, $action, $version);
dd($lr);
```

I get this:
[Too long to be here. It's on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ytZ7U2kE)

When i try this:

```
$xml = new \DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($lr);
$i = 0;        
while(is_object($productos = $xml->getElementsByTagName('Productos')->item($i))) {
    foreach($productos->childNodes as $nodename) {
        echo $i.": ".$nodename->nodeName." - ".$nodename->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

I get this: [Result with products](http://pastebin.com/94PnUnd1)

Now, i want to do something like this:

```
 foreach ($productos as $producto) {
    $referencia_dist = trim($producto->IdProducto);
    $mpn = trim($producto->PartNumber); 
    $ean = trim($producto->UpcCode);
    and son on....
}
```

But i get stacked here. Any hints???

Answer (score 0):

OK! Got the solution! It is easier than i thought... Perhaps, that's the reason why i didn't find it...

```
while(is_object($productos = $xml->getElementsByTagName('Productos')->item($i))){
          $nombre = "";
          $IdCategoria = "";
        foreach($productos->childNodes as $producto)
                 {
                     switch ($producto->nodename){
                      case 'IdProducto':
                          $IdProducto = $producto->nodeValue;
                      case 'IdTarifa':
                          $IdTarifa = $producto->nodeValue;
                      case 'MostrarComparadores':
                          $MostrarComparadores = $producto->nodeValue;
                      case....
```

}